# How to execute a function in the cell on the right of every row of a specific range?

Tags: vba, loops, excel, split

Earlier i was trying to sum every column of a range in the cell right below and got successfully helped. I'm just trying to modify the code i received to do the same for every row and get the result in the column just on the right

```
Sub miine()

Dim a, i As Integer, Data, sums As Range
a = InputBox("How many cells for the square?")
Set Data = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(a - 1, a - 1))

Set sums = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(a, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(a, a - 1))
For Each cell In sums
cell.Value = "=SUM(" & Split(cell.Address, "$")(1) & cell.Row - a & ":" & Split(cell.Address, "$")(1) & cell.Row - 1 & ")"
Next

Set sum = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, a), ActiveCell.Offset(a - 1, a))
For each cell in sum
cell.Value = "=SUM(" & cell.Column - a & Split(cell.Address, "$")(2) & ":" & cell.Column - 1 & Split(cell.Address, "$")(2) & ")"

End Sub
```

The second part doesn't work, i get the sum in place on the right, but the range selected for the sum appears like that Range(11:41) instead of Range("A1:D1"). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cell.Address is something like this: "`$A$1`"; the function `Split` is splitting by the symbol `$` so the letter `A` will be contained at position `(1)` of the array while the row number `1` at the position `(2)`. That's why your:

```
Split(cell.Address, "$")(2)
```

is returning a number and not a letter. What you want to do is probably:

```
Set sum = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, a), ActiveCell.Offset(a - 1, a))
For each cell in sum
    cell.Value = "=SUM(" & Split(cell.Offset(0,-a).Address,"$")(1) & cell.Row & ":" & Split(cell.Offset(0,-1).Address,"$")(1) & cell.Row & ")"  
Next cell
```

Comment: Note: I've copied-pasted your code, but avoid (in general) using keywords such as "sum" to name variables of other kind. They might sometimes be reserved keywords.

Comment: Once again it works perfectly! I'll dig into the split function ;) Thanks a lot!